# How to keep id in array after reloading page and add new one?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to check that the id is already written to the array and add the id to the existing array of elements when adding a new element?

I was thinking about something like that: firstly, to check if such id is existed and was added to array, secondly, I want to check if when getting a list of databases, go through using for-loop and write the id that are selected immediately into the array of selected id.

Now when I refresh the page, it shows me an empty array in the print without the selected data, but I want it to show me what ids are in the array and just add new ids to this array

I wrote code like this:

```
/// new array where I want store and keep data and add new id without getting empty list after reloading 
    List multipleSelected = [];
///original array from API call
    List baseNames = []
     for (var elementInDataBase in baseNames) {
                        var value = multipleSelected.any((existedElementinArray) =>
                            existedElementinArray == elementInDataBase);
                        if (value == false && selected == true) {
                          return multipleSelected.add(id);
                        } else {
                          multipleSelected.remove(id);
                        }
                      }
```

And this code should work when I tap on checkboxes to select value:

```
Checkbox(
                          activeColor: Colors.green,
                          tristate: true,
                          checkColor: Colors.green,
                          side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.white),
                          value: baseNames[i]['isCheked'],
                          onChanged: (bool? selected) {
                            baseNames[i]['isCheked'] = selected;
                            setState(() {
                              _onCategorySelected(
                                  selected ?? false, baseNames[i]['id']);
                            });
                          },
                        )),
```

Comment: Could you please include code that modifies `selected` value?

Comment: @KasymbekR.Tashbaev I added more code for clarification